# Expo AppLoading and app bootstrap data?

Tags: react-native, expo

There is a new component `<AppLoading/>` that is supposed to let the splash screen remain visible while loading app resources.

The example in the doc is pretty straightforward

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/app-loading.html

```
import React from 'react';
import { Image, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Asset, AppLoading } from 'expo';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isReady: false,
  };

  render() {
    if (!this.state.isReady) {
      return (
        <AppLoading
          startAsync={this._cacheResourcesAsync}
          onFinish={() => this.setState({ isReady: true })}
          onError={console.warn}
        />
      );
    }

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Image source={require('./assets/images/expo-icon.png')} />
        <Image source={require('./assets/images/slack-icon.png')} />
      </View>
    );
  }

  async _cacheResourcesAsync() {
    const images = [
      require('./assets/images/expo-icon.png'),
      require('./assets/images/slack-icon.png'),
    ];

    const cacheImages = images.map((image) => {
      return Asset.fromModule(image).downloadAsync();
    });
    return Promise.all(cacheImages)

  }
}
```

However is this kind of component intended to handle loading resources that can fail?

Like for example if my app needs bootstrap datas regarding the authenticated users, provided by a backend, should I use this component?

If AppLoading is suited for this need, how would you handle the case where the user starts the app with no connexion, and the bootstrap data promise rejects? How do you handle retry attempts?